# Sending Authenticated SMTP Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I have purchased an authenticated SMTP package with my hosting company.

I have tested the account settings via Outlook 2010 successfully.

Outlook settings:

**Email**: me@domain.com
**Outgoing SMTP**: smtp.hostingcompany.net

**Logon Info:**

- **user**: mydomain.com_account
- **pass**: password

**More Settings > Outgoing Server:**

- My Outgoing Server (SMTP) Requires authentication
- **User**: mydomain
- **Pass**: password

I have tried all possible combinations when specifying the NetworkCredentials and I keep getting an **SMTP Exception**: "Faulure Sending Email"
**InnerException**: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

```
public static void SendEmail(string To, string Subject, string Body)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(GlobalSettings.EmailHost))
            {
                mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                //mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
                mySmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mydomain.com_account, GlobalSettings.EmailPassword);

                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@mydomain");
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(To);

                using (
                    MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage(from, to)
                    {
                        Subject = Subject,
                        SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                        Body = Body,
                        BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                        IsBodyHtml = true
                    })
                {
                    mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLog(string.Format("[Send Mail Exception] --> SMTPException has occurred: {0}", ex.Message), LogLevel.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLog(string.Format("[Send Mail Exception] --> Exception has occurred: {0}", ex.Message), LogLevel.Error);
        }
    }
```

I have tried three possible username login parameters for the NetworkCredential().

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: NTLM Hack**

I added the following lines to my code:

```
FieldInfo transport = _client.GetType().GetField("transport",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

FieldInfo authModules = transport.GetValue(_client).GetType()
    .GetField("authenticationModules",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Array modulesArray = authModules.GetValue(transport.GetValue(_client)) as Array;
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 0);
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 1);
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 3);
```

I am now getting a new message:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: relay not permitted
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of your exception? There are a couple of places where this could pop up. A stack trace would help narrow this down.

Comment: @Ragesh - Just added it there. Do I need to encode the body property of the MailMessage object as I am passing in HTML?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to encode the body manually. I'm using HTML bodies, too, and it encodes it automatically.

Comment: Relay not permitted usually happens if your server doesn't like your From or To addresses (it thinks you're a spammer). Or, it could be your user account isn't being authenticated properly.

In cases like this, I find that using Wireshark to take a peek at the network traffic is the quickest way to a solution. Send a mail with Outlook, then your code and identify what's different between your SMTP requests and what Outlook is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following article: ["Hacking" System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2008/04/16/hacking-system-net-mail-smtpclient.aspx), the exception could be thrown when the SmtpClient chooses to authenticate using [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) authentication.

The article provides a fix, although as the article name suggests it is a hack.

However in the comments a poster also notes that an incorrect password can cause the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Re your second problem:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: relay not permitted

This happens because the server now has no acceptable method of authenticating you, and is unwilling to risk getting a reputation as an "open relay".

This is probably fixable. The problem is that the [hack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2008/04/16/hacking-system-net-mail-smtpclient.aspx) you're using is too heavy handed. It is overwriting every authentication module except "Digest", when all we need to do is overwrite NTLM.

Try this cut-down version:

```
FieldInfo transport = _client.GetType().GetField("transport",
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

FieldInfo authModules = transport.GetValue(_client).GetType()
    .GetField("authenticationModules",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Array modulesArray = authModules.GetValue(transport.GetValue(_client)) as Array;
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 1);
```

Comment: This is really good to know. I will look at implementing your cut-down version in a future release cycle.